# Why do R and C have to be small for differentiator circuit

Tags: capacitor, resistors, passive-networks

I'm a beginner studying *The Art of Electronics*, and on page 25 they introduce the differentiator.  Basic circuit like so:

[image: RC Diff Circuit]

They give the complete equation:

$$
I = C \frac{d}{dt}(V_{in} - V) = {V\over R}
$$

I understand this so far.  But then they say: *if we choose R and C small 
enough so that* \$\frac{dV}{dt} \ll \frac{dV_{in}}{dt}\$, *then...*

$$
C\frac{dV_{in}}{dt} \approx \frac{V}{R}
$$

This I don't follow. Can someone elaborate or explain a bit more? I see why the above equation makes it a differentiator -- V is proportional to \$\frac{dV_{in}}{dt}\$.  But why does a small R and C cause the one derivative to me much less than the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you rearrange the first equation, you get

\$C\dfrac{dV_{in}}{dt} = \dfrac{V}{R} + C\dfrac{dV}{dt}\$

So if you reduce *C* enough, you'll make the derivative term on the right insignificant compared to *V/R*, and you'll get your second equation.

Alternately, if you reduce *R*, you'll make the *V/R* term larger, and again the right-hand-side derivative term will become insignificant, and you'll get the desired result.

So I'd say it's not that you must decrease *R* and *C* together, but you do have do some combination of reducing *R* and reducing *C* to make the circuit work like a differentiator.

Comment: It becomes even more clear if you divide through by C, which puts the R*C product in a term by itself. It's that product that needs to be small, which makes the V/RC term large.

Comment: I find that H&H tend to skip a few too many steps in their explanations, making their line of thinking hard to follow at times, even for experienced engineers. The non-mathematical (hand-waving) description of this example is that the R-C time constant needs to be small -- the cutoff frequency 1/RC needs to be large with respect to the signal frequencies -- so that nearly all of the input voltage appears across the C, and the voltage across the R is almost entirely due to the current, which is the derivative of the input voltage.

Comment: @DaveTweed "I find that H&H tend to skip a few too many steps in their explanations, making their line of thinking hard to follow at times" I couldn't stop writing to you how much I agree with your comment. It is a great book but I dont know why they skip many derivations which makes things painful..

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at this is in the frequency domain rather than the time domain.

What you have is a passive 1st order RC high pass filter.  The transfer function is:

\$\dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \dfrac{j\omega RC}{1 + j \omega RC}\$

When \$ \omega << \frac{1}{RC}\$

\$\dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} \approx j \omega RC\$

But this is just the transfer function of an ideal differentiator.

The requirement given in the text is essentially the same requirement as above.  The basic idea is that this high-pass filter "looks like" a differentiator well below the corner frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *RC* is small, we want to solve:

$$RC\frac{dV_{in}}{dt}=V+RC\frac{dV}{dt}.$$

I was a bit unsatisfied as to why we would neglect the term *RCV'(t)* on the right, but not *RCVin'(t)* on the left. So instead let's find a solution using power series.

We will abbreviate the derivative as *D*, so:

$$DV_{in}=\frac{dV_{in}}{dt};\;DV=\frac{dV}{dt}.$$

Let's also abbreviate

$$\epsilon=RC.$$

The equation is then

$$\epsilon DV_{in}=V+\epsilon DV,$$
$$(1+\epsilon D)V=\epsilon DV_{in}.$$

Now, we 'divide both sides by (1+ϵD)', which can be made rigorous using power series. This gives the solution

$$V=\frac{1}{1+\epsilon D}\epsilon DV_{in}.$$

Assuming *ϵ=RC* is small, we can use the power series expansion

$$\frac{1}{1+x}\approx 1-x,$$

which is valid whenever *x* is small. This gives

$$V\approx \epsilon DV_{in}-\epsilon^2D^2V_{in}=RC\frac{dV_{in}}{dt}-(RC)^2\frac{d^2V_{in}}{dt^2}.$$

For small *RC* we can neglect the second term.

To be precise, we need *(RC)D* to be small. Note that this is unitless, since *RC* has units of time, and the derivative *D* has units inverse time. In other words, the time constant *RC* has to be small compared to the rate at which our signal *Vin* changes.