# RC integrator circuit - can a high RC product really by approximately equal to Vin / R?

Tags: integrator

This question is very much related to [Why do R and C have to be small for differentiator circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39352/why-do-r-and-c-have-to-be-small-for-differentiator-circuit) asked earlier.

On page 26 of Art Of Electronics, 2nd Edition, the book makes the statement that if we manage to keep \$V\$ much less than \$V_{in}\$, by keeping the product \$RC\$ large, then.

$$
C {dV \over dt} 
$$

is approximately equal to

$$
V_{in} \over R
$$

The original equation, prior to simplification, is

$$
I = C {dV \over dt} = { { V_{in} - V } \over R }
$$

Why is this so?  Or, Why must we manage a relation of \$V\$ and \$V_{in}\$ by juggling \$R\$ and \$C\$.

I know \$RC\$ is the time constant.  I suspect that if you make it long enough, \$V\$ can always be made to be less than \$V_{in}\$ given some \$dV \over dt\$. If that is so, I see the simplification above.

However if I expand the original equation I am not seeing it mathematically.

$$
I = C {dV \over dt} = { { V_{in} \over R } - { V \over R } }
$$

Yeah, if you make \$R\$ large enough, \$V \over R\$ will be insignificant, but won't \$V_{in} \over R\$ be getting close to insignificant as well? Is it always the case the \$V\$ will be less than \$V_{in}\$. If so, I see the simplification above.

[image]

Comment: To help other readers, I've edited your question to link to the question which I *think* you mean. However if you meant a different question, please edit and change the link.

Comment: It would be better to post a picture of the circuit or draw one with the tool links are discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A large time constant (a large value of RC), means that V will never grow large relative to Vin (It will eventually of course, but we're approximating).

Another way of putting it, is that the current through the resistor is relatively constant because V isn't changing, and this is accomplished  by making R or C (or both) large.

Imagine a resistor charging an "infinite" capacitor, the voltage on the capacitor would be constant. Similarly, if the resistor is infinite, voltage doesn't change either. Now obviously, neither of these cases is useful, V needs to change at least a bit to be helpful, but hopefully that helps you see where the approximation comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I think the book is alluding to something like this: -

[image]

Here we have a capacitor being charged from a square wave via a series resistor. It looks like a triangular waveform (i.e. what an integrator would produce with the same square wave) but if you allowed the capacitor a longer time to charge (i.e. slowed down the frequency of the square wave) you'd get a more obvious exponential charge/discharge waveform.

If Vout only changes a little bit (because the frequency is significantly higher or R or C increased significantly), then the waveform would look more like an integration function. See the three slightly exaggerated options below: -

[image]

Comment: The book is specifically talking about Integrators.  The book, at least to me, reads as follows...If you change the RC product, you get the approximation.  I was wondering the reasoning behind the causality.

Comment: I don't have the book but, despite your comment, I believe my answer still stands. Maybe post an image of the page.

Comment: I just added the image.  Thanks.  I have to get my head around this.  The post below was also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you read section 1.14 Differentiators (2nd edition) or 1.4.3 (3rd edition), you might understand a bit more of what the authors is saying.

The idea behind it is that you want V to die out **faster** than Vin.

$$  \frac {dV}{dt} = \frac{V_{in}}{RC} - \frac{V}{RC} $$

So if RC is large, then both terms \$ \frac{V_{in}}{RC} \$ and \$ \frac{V}{RC} \$ decrease in value.

But if V << Vin, now V will  be much smaller than Vin.

And what you are left with is an expression that is proportional to just the integral of Vin and not Vin - V.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain it mathematically, it's actually quite straightforward.

First move the R to the left hand side so you get $$RC \frac{dV}{dt}=V_{in}-V$$

Now if \$RC\$ is very large, it means \$V_{in}-V\$ is also very large right? So what does that mean for \$V\$ in relation to \$V_{in}\$? For e.g. if I tell you that A-B is very large, that means that B is very small compared to A right? Similarly, if RC is large, then we can assume that \$V<<V_{in}\$, and then we get the approximation of an integrator. Similar explanation can be used for the differentiator. Since the differentiation operator is linear, so $$\frac{d}{dt}(V_{in}-V)=\frac{dV_{in}}{dt}-\frac{dV}{dt}$$ and you continue from there using similar arguments as above.